# Factory value not updated in model ...what I am doing wrong?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular-js. I have two controllers (welcomeContoller,productController) and both handling the same model within the factory.

When the model getting updating by one controller(productController) it should reflect the update in another controller. (welcomeContoller)

But its not happening now.

HTML code :

```
 <body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="welcomeContoller">
  {{totalProductCnt}}
</div>
<div ng-controller="productController">
  <div class="addRemoveCart">
    <span class="pull-left glyphicon glyphicon-minus" ng-click="removeProduct()"></span>
    <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ng-click="addProduct(1)"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS code

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);
myApp.factory("productCountFactory", function() {
  return {
    totalProducts:0
  };
});
myApp.controller("welcomeContoller", function($scope, productCountFactory) 
{
  $scope.totalProductCnt = productCountFactory.totalProducts;
});

 myApp.controller("productController", function($scope, productCountFactory) {
   $scope.addProduct = function() {
productCountFactory.totalProducts++;
alert(productCountFactory.totalProducts);
     };
  $scope.removeProduct = function() {
     if(productCountFactory.totalProducts >=1)
         productCountFactory.totalProducts--;
        alert(productCountFactory.totalProducts);
     };
    });
```

Even after the addProduct is called the totalProductCnt  is displaying as zero. I want to display the value for each increment.

[Plunkr Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/qkH4ws8Ki6LOPTMGgBsV?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the factory object reference on scope:

```
myApp.controller("welcomeContoller", function($scope, productCountFactory) {

    $scope.productCountFactory = productCountFactory;

});
```

Watch the property of the object.

```
  {{productCountFactory.totalProducts}}
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/sYnbUCluUvYusfQ7mASg?p=preview).

By putting a *reference* on scope, on every digest cycle the watcher looks up the value of the property and updates the DOM if there is a change.

Answer (score 1):

The totalProductCnt from your welcomeCont**r**oller isn't updated because it is assigned only once when the controller is created.

You can use several solutions to refresh the displayed value. Use a getter for your totalProducts in the factory :

```
myApp.factory("productCountFactory", function() {
    var totalProducts = 0;
    return {
        getTotalProducts: function() {
            return totalProducts;
        },
        addProduct: function() {
            totalProducts++;
        },
        removeProduct: function() {
            totalProducts--;
        }
    };
});
myApp.controller("welcomeContoller", function($scope, productCountFactory) {
    $scope.getTotalProducts = productCountFactory.getTotalProducts;
});

myApp.controller("productController", function($scope, productCountFactory) {
    $scope.addProduct = function() {
        productCountFactory.addProduct();
    };
    $scope.removeProduct = function() {
        if (productCountFactory.getTotalProducts() >= 1)
            productCountFactory.removeProduct();
    };
});
```

And update the view accordingly:

```
<div ng-controller="welcomeContoller">
  {{getTotalProducts()}}
</div>
```

[Plunkr Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/4YO8VZID2tgc4BVnD3aJ?p=preview)

Comment: Can you setup a plunkr for this?

Comment: I've added a plunkr link.